# Storing and processing timezone information in Django Datetime fields

Tags: django, timezone

I am designing a service which lists events happening around the world. The users can contribute to the lists as well. I'd designed it earlier for a particular place where timezone was same all across but now that it is global, I'll need to store and process timezone information for each event as well; the user will provide the timezone. The listings should now list local time as well as time relative to the viewing user. I also have to do some processing on the events that are happening right now so I'll need to compare the time with current time conveniently.

I've gone through Django's documentation of timezone but I'm not sure if I'll need to store 
timezone information for event in a separate field or can I store the timezone be right within DatetimeField? If I can't store it in DatetimeField, will I have to manually perform the conversions each time before displaying? I have some cronjobs too so a middleware approach to set timezone might not be useful.